# Pycharm debug odoo11 on windows10 raise error with code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Tags: pycharm, windows-10, odoo-11

I have a problem with pycharm debug mode.

I can normally run but can't debug with same configuration.

when I try to debug,

Pycharm except as below:

"""

C:\Users\wangy\PycharmProjects\odoo\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\wangy\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\181.4445.76\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52044 --file C:/Users/wangy/PycharmProjects/odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo.conf

pydev debugger: process 11956 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.4445.76)

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

"""

PyCharm 2018.1.1 (Professional Edition)

Build #PY-181.4445.76, built on April 10, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

Python 3.6.8 64bit